# Javascript search and remove multiple object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi Could someone please help me with my problem below.
I have an array:

```
var testarray = [AB_C_D, AC_B_D, PPLL_Y_N, PPMM_Y_N, PPDD_Y_N]
```

I want to remove object which contains PP* so that my final array will look like

```
var testarray = [AB_C_D, AC_B_D]
```

I cannot remove with index number because position of these objects will be different.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var testarray = [
  'AB_C_D',
  'AC_B_D',
  'PPLL_Y_N',
  'PPMM_Y_N',
  'PPDD_Y_N'
]

const result = testarray.filter(str => !str.startsWith('PP'))
console.log(result)
```